# Convert in Ketubah

Tags: words, women, conversion-to-judaism, sexuality, ketubah

In a ketubah, there are 3 different categories for the woman's status. Virgin, Convert, and woman. Usually one of those statuses is represented on the ketubah, with the appropriate amount in zuzim. And while it may not be conventionally done, is writing more than one status actually forbidden? Can the kallah be listed as a convert and a virgin if both those things were true? If it's not possible to mention both these things in the same statement, can one be mentioned in one statement and the other in a different statement of the ketubah.

Update
The comments and answers have not been satisfying. They seem to be under the assumption that i am asking how to change something that is fixed in stone already and should not be messed with. i do not think this applies because ketubot have historically been some of the broadest and most updated documents within the Sephardic world (of which i am). There were even new categories other than divorce, virgin, and convert. Another class that was codified by the Rambam was the ransomed captive (Mishneh Torah "laws of Yibbum wa-Halisa 4:34). And there are documents that are preserved in our tradition that list multiple statuses for the bride.

"and willingly this Berukha, the bride, the virgin, the divrocee, took upon herself and became to this Yeshu'a the groom, a wife and the mother of children..."
See line 7 in the Aramaic and the English. This document is not a document of accident or ignorance, as it was written and signed by Elijah Gaon, the head of the Yeshiva of Ramle.

[image: Aramaic]

[image: English Translation]

[image: Copy of original]

So my question isn't "can this be done?" Because it already has been done. My question is "has listing more than one status become *specifically* forbidden?" Saying that a kallah should be one or the other in terms of her zuz price and to let it be known that she cannot marry a Cohen is fine, but i still haven't heard that it's illegal to mention more details elsewhere.

Comment: Interesting question. My understanding is that it goes by the lowest zuz amount having priority. My friend was both a convert and betulah, but she was listed as a convert. She remarried after being an almanah, and I think she was listed as a convert, as I think this is the lowest zuz amount.

Comment: i understand that the zuz amount would remain lower. And that the lower zuz amount has to be reflected, and that the convert status has to remain the first mention, but is mentioning the virgin status forbidden?

Comment: Your comment seems to reflect that you know for a fact that the lower amount is what's used. If that's the case, logically, wouldn't the category have to match the amount? After all, only a single amount is allowed to be listed. Therefore, how could you place more than 1 category?

Comment: Why do you want to write virgin if she's a convert? Do you also want to mention her hair color?

Comment: No i don't want to mention her hair color. But her virginity is an important aspect of her religious ideal. The ketubah is going to be decorated and hung in the house, she wants her children to be able to see it and know that she reserved herself for her husband as an aspect of chinuch and familial expectation.

Comment: @Aaron So have a doctor inspect her and write her a signed and dated Certification of Virginity to hang proudly in her dining room. No need to go messing with the Ketubah.

Comment: i don't understand how this is messing with the ketubah?

Comment: @Aaron Including pointless information is "messing with the ketubah" as far as I can tell. That doesn't make it forbidden. It just seems like an accurate description of the situation. It's possible that there is no prohibition on mentioning her shoe size, bra size or the shape of her hymen; that doesn't mean you should do it.

Comment: i guess it doesn't seem like messing of the ketubah since i've studied a lot of ancient ketubot and those descriptions were the norm. The ones i've seen in my lifetime don't seem to mention any details, not even a list of possessions that the woman brings into the home. So maybe we are approaching the same thing from two different perspectives. My only concern was whether halakha has since forbidden things that were once common, like rendering the year minyan shetarot.

Answer (score 9):

In general, only one status is needed to be listed.
For a Jewish born virgin, besulah is written because she is due 200 zuz upon divorce/death of husband.
For a Jewish born "widow" (I'm not sure why you wrote "woman"), almanah is written because she is due 100 zuz upon termination of the marriage.
For a Jewish born divorcee, gerushah is written because even though she recieves 100 zuz like an almanah, we are careful to note that she is a gerushah so that she will not marry a Kohen. 
For a convert, the term giyores is written in her kesubah (even though she recieves the same 100 zuz as an almanah and is forbidden to a kohen like a gerushah) so that one will realize that if she marries a male convert, her daughter will be forbidden to a Kohen.
A woman cannot be a besulah and any of the other categories so that question is moot. A woman who is both an almanah and a gerushah writes in her kesubah gersuhah so that people will know she cannot marry a kohen. A woman who is both an almanah and giyores writes that she is a giyores so that people will know she is forbidden from marrying a kohen. A woman who is both a gerushah and a giyores is subject to dispute: Pischei Teshuva (Even HaEzer 66:8) quotes from Radvaz that she writes Giyores, while the recenly departed Rabbi Shmuel Wosner rules that she she writes both giyores and gerushah. I have a whole explanation of why Rabbi Wosner would rule so but it is my own understanding and is quite complicated.

Comment: Thorough answer! If possible, please link whatever sources that you can.

Comment: What I quoted from Rabbi Wosner is found in the work of his student Rabbi Shmuel Eliezer Stern called Kesubah K'Hilchasa.

Comment: So what do you make of the ketubah I posted which listed a divorcee and virgin?